# Debug statement execution counter

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to get statements execution counter in Visual Studio in C#? 
So that when I encounter a bug after long digging into code with debugger, with many loops, and I want to step into function that caused the problem and I already went past it with debugger. So I could put this line before the problematic function:

```
if (Global_execution_counter == 5484984)
 int d = 0; // put debug breakpoint here
execute_problematic_function (); // wanna step into this function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can and without any global variable counter.
The solution is using a [hit count breakpoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2013/10/07/hit-count-breakpoints/).

Set a breakpoint at `execute_problematic_function ();`; right click it to bring up the context menu:

[image: breakpoint context menu]

Then click "Conditions", select "Hit count" and set it to whatever value you want.

[image: Hit count condition]

If you still don't know what's the hit count that you need to set the breakpoint to, [you can take advantage of the breakpoints window](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/zainnab/2010/04/28/breakpoint-hit-count/), which will tell you the current value of the breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: Aha, now i only need to figure out how I can view this hitcount.

Comment: You mean that you don't know the value that you should step into your function at?

Comment: Yes, I don't know what I should put for value where you put 36. And it seems there is no such info.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to include a suggestion on how to trap the exact value (be it 36 or 5484984 like in your example).

Comment: That is a lot of work IMO. I can always see what values caused the bug and set breakpoint at the condition of those values. But it would be easier if global statement execution counter existed. This "hit count" value must be stored somewhere.

Comment: you are right, there is a smarter way indeed. I edited my answer, you can check the hit count value in the breakpoints window.

Comment: Thanks man, that works! In vs 2015 you can see this value AFTER you set hit count. So it's a little hidden.